# What is the relationship between the Mono Execution Environment and the ART?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble getting a solid understanding of how the Mono Execution environment interacts with Android...

So if each Application runs in its own ART, does that mean a separate Mono environment is run for each Xamarin app?  How would these two diagrams fit together?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture
https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/

Comment: `Xamarin.Android` "constructs" an NDK-based app and thus provides access two VM runtimes; the Java ART and the Mono Runtime.

Comment: Is the Mono Runtime created for each App? IE on android each app gets its own ART, curious if that means each xamarin app gets its own Mono Runtime as well

Comment: `each app gets its own ART` If by this you mean its own OS **process**, then kind-of, Mono is a shared library within the NDK-based app and thus is bound within that app's process. If you mean physically, then Android does not package a separate ART .so in each app, but Xamarin.Android does package a separate Mono runtime in each app.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your replies! So my understanding is that each app has its own process with its own instance of the ART. So for each app running on android, there are multiple ART virtual machines running. Does the mono runtime work simmilarly, or is it more like a native library that gets called by the ART? Or is Mono its own virtual machine that each app's process has a unique instance of?

Comment: From this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture it makes me believe that the mono runtime is a native android app using the NDK. That "mono app" handles the execution of your c# code by calling into the ART... but is the mono runtime unique for each process?

Comment: The Mono Runtime is unique to each "app" and thus is within each Xamarin.Android app's sandboxed processes